# In ReFS what is the method of checksum generation?

Tags: checksum, refs

In ReFS what is the method of checksum generation? I haven't been able to find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a very classical CRC 64. It uses the same polynom as NTFS from what i know. It is used to check sum the metadata and optionally to check sum the clusters of data files. Look at the sources of ntfs-3g if you want more details.

Best regards.